# R shiny group multiple textOutputs

Tags: r, shiny

I want to group some textOutput() values together neatly in a box. I know this can be done using shinydashboard::box(), but that would mean changing everything in my app layout, which I don't want to do. Is there any way to do this in base shiny itself?

I want a simple box around my textOutputs, preferably separated from and below the sidebarPanel.

Reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("var", choices = c("mpg", "disp"), label = "Selected Input"),
    textOutput("foo1"),
    textOutput("foo2"),
    textOutput("foo3"),
    textOutput("foo4")
 ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1", hover = "plot_hover")
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
 ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = 'wt', y=input$var)) + geom_point()
})
output$foo1 <- renderText("This is text output 1")
output$foo2 <- renderText("This is text output 2")
output$foo3 <- renderText("This is text output 3")
output$foo4 <- renderText("This is text output 4")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And the app:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

A separate box that groups my textOutputs at one place, outside and below the sidbarPanel area

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "box"? What exactly do you want the output to look like? Can you draw a picture of the desired output?

Comment: Edited my question with a picture of the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can draw simple "boxes" by adding in a `<div>` tag and giving it a border. For example

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("var", choices = c("mpg", "disp"), label = "Selected Input"),
    div(style="border:1px solid red",
      textOutput("foo1"),
      textOutput("foo2"),
      textOutput("foo3"),
      textOutput("foo4")
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1", hover = "plot_hover")
  )
)
```

Or you can add a class attribute. You will just need to do the styling yourself with CSS.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting <div>. Is there any way I can add it separate from and below my sidebarPanel?

Comment: I don't really understand what that means. You can lay things out however you want with HTML/CSS. Things like this don't really have anything to do specifically with R or Shiny.